# MySQL Category Count

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I'm trying to make a search filter that displays categories with an item count. I have a category/post relationship table as follows

```
entry_id | cat_id
------------------
    1    |   1
------------------
    1    |   3
------------------
    2    |   1
------------------
    3    |   2
------------------
    3    |   3
------------------
```

What I'm trying to do is display a post total for each category. I have manged to acheive an absolute solution where a definite total is output is displayed as follows:

```
SELECT count(entry_id) as count FROM cat_rel_table WHERE cat_id = $i;
```

What i'm trying to acheive is a more relative count that calculates how many items are categorised in all 'active' categories. So I want be albe to specify more than one cat_id. And it would count how many items are categorised under these categories combined. Something along the lines of this:

```
SELECT count(entry_id) as count FROM cat_rel_table WHERE cat_id IN(1, 3);
```

But only on the condition that a category has an item that also belongs to another active category.

Comment: How are you determining whether a category is "active"?

Answer (score 2):

Use GROUP BY.

```
SELECT count(entry_id) as count, cat_id 
FROM cat_rel_table 
WHERE cat_id IN(1, 3) 
GROUP BY cat_id
```

Then you can modify that `IN()` clause to filter the "active" categories.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for the "Group By" clause.

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp